# Update one table based on data from two other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have 3 tables ADDRESS, PERS_INFO, ADDRESS_NEW with following dummy data

```
ADDRESS
-----------------------
ID | CITY | LINE1
21 |  abc |   def
22 |  fgh |   ijk


PERS_INFO
---------------------------------------
ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | ADDR_ID
45 | Jennifer   | Higgins   | 21
46 | John       | Craig     | 22

ADDRESS_NEW
---------------------
ID | CITY | LINE1
1  | abc  | def
2  | fgh  | ijk
```

I want to write a single query in Oracle to replace `ADDR_ID` values in `PERS_INFO` with `ID` values of `ADDRESS_NEW` table.
Remember this is just dummy data and I want to write a generic query without any data in UPDATE statements. Please help !!

Here's my code which I have tried.

```
UPDATE PERS_INFO
      SET PERS_INFO.ADDR_ID =
             (SELECT ADDRESS_NEW.ID FROM ADDRESS_NEW, ADDRESS 
               WHERE ADDRESS.ID = PERS_INFO.ADDR_ID);
```

Comment: I want to write a single query in Oracle to replace `ADDR_ID` values in `PERS_INFO` with `ID` values of `ADDRESS_NEW` table.

Comment: How do you know which `ID` from `ADDRESS_NEW` to use for which row of `PERS_INFO`?  Should the `PERS_INFO` row with `ID` 45 end up with an `ADDR_ID` of 1 or 2?  What about 46?  Why?  Does the `ADDRESS` table have something to do with figuring this out?

Comment: This question is tagged both [tag:oracle] (a closed-source commercial RDBMS product from the Oracle Corporation) and [tag:mysql] (an open-source free RDBMS product that now happens also to be owned by the Oracle Corporation).  Which are you using?

Comment: can you just update the add_id to be addr_id-20? otherwise you would need to join on all fields(or key fields) to get the proper new address id

Comment: @JustinCave yes, you're right `PERS_INFO` row with `ID` 45 end up with an `ADDR_ID` of 1 because there will be a replacement of `ADDR_ID` of `PERS_INFO` with `ID` of `ADDRESS_NEW` when ever there is a match of `ID` of `ADDR` and `ADDR_ID` of `PERS_INFO`.

Comment: @eggyal I am using Oracle with TOAD. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @stead I have to use the joins and everything because this is just dummy data, the actual data is way different than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updated query below:

```
update pers_info
   set pers_info.addr_id =
       (select y.id
          from (select address.*,
                       row_number() over(order by address.rowid) as link
                  from address
                  join pers_info
                    on address.id = pers_info.addr_id) x
          join (select address_new.*,
                      row_number() over(order by address.rowid) as link
                 from address_new
                 join pers_info
                   on address.id = pers_info.addr_id) y
            on x.link = y.link
         where x.id = pers_info.addr_id)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a problem because city and line1 could be duplicates as well ?

Comment: It could be if there are 2+ IDs with the same city and line1 value, yes, but given your data there is nothing connecting ADDRESS_NEW with ADDRESS other than those two fields, unless those tables have columns you didn't give in the example.

Comment: Those two tables `ADDRESS` and `ADDRESS_NEW` are exactly the same with same number of columns but it is highly likely that there will be more than 2+ IDs having same `city` and `line1`.

Comment: @arpit_s Then it is logically impossible for you to do this because there is nothing that connects ADDRESS_NEW to ADDRESS.

Comment: Wouldn't it at all be possible with the use of a cursor or some other PL/SQL ? If I could hold the `ID`s of `ADDRESS` into some cursor and keep on updating the `PERS_INFO`'s `ADDR_ID` based on cursor

Comment: If it can't be described in words how you would determine what row of ADDRESS_NEW corresponds to each row of ADDRESS, there is no way to program anything to do it. You're trying to derive something without the necessary data, it's like trying to solve for C when A + B = C and you only know A.

Comment: The data in the `ADDRESS_NEW` is exact replica of `ADDRESS` with just the new `ID`s because the goal is to attach a FK relationship between `PERS_INFO` and `ADDRESS_NEW` based upon `ADDR_ID` and `ID` so that's where comes the data replacement in `PERS_INFO` `ADDR_ID` column to obtain a relationship.
Here's the SQL which populated `ADDRESS_NEW`
`INSERT INTO ADDRESS_NEW (CITY, LINE1) (SELECT ADDRESS.CITY, ADDRESS.LINE1 FROM ADDRESS, PERS_INFO WHERE ADDRESS.ID = PERS_INFO.ADDR_ID);` 
The IDs of `ADDRESS_NEW` are auto-generated IDs.

Comment: @arpit_s Could you remake the ADDRESS_NEW table and include the old ID column in the insert (temporarily)? That would easily allow you to do what you want. You can always get rid of the column after you do the update on PERS_INFO.

Comment: That was my original approach to have a temp column in ADDRESS_NEW to hold the IDs which I was able to work thru, but I have to do it without the temp column.

Comment: If the tables (ADDRESS and ADDRSS_NEW) hold associated rows in the exact same order you MIGHT be able to use rowid. Just so I have an idea of how much data we're talking about, how many rows does each have?

Comment: There are more than 100,000 rows where `ADDRESS.ID` = `PERS_INFO.ADDR_ID`

Comment: Try running the 2nd query that I just added to my answer. Can you let me know if the old IDs and new IDs are properly matched up?

Comment: Yes the Old IDs and New Ids match up.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to tell you that there could be more data in ADDRESS which is not copied into ADDRESS_NEW.

Comment: I just made another edit, try the new one. It has joins w/ pers_info. This assumes that you took all address from ADDRESS and put them into ADDRESS_NEW where the address id existed in PERS_INFO.